# How to update timestamps for has_many records in Rails with ActiveRecord / PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Table Relation: Table A has_many Table B

I need to update the `created_at` and `updated_at` values of `TableA` to `created_at` and `updated_at` of `TableB`.

I need to update all the records.

My solution:

```
Table_B.all.map{ |child| child.update(created_at: child.table_a.created_at) }
```

Since  Table B has almost 500 000 records what will be the best solution to solve it?

Comment: What is the relation between A & B? Also nobody knows what a Lakh is in the west.

Comment: Table A has_many Table B. For example Primary key from Table A have minimum of 30 record in Table B. 5 Lakh which means 500000 records.

Comment: Is this something that needs to be done one time, or is it something that needs to be done on every future transaction?

Comment: Are you updating the records in TableA or TableB? If TableA, how do you know which Table B created_at to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use single query with subquery:

```sql
UPDATE table_b
SET (created_at, updated_at) = (SELECT created_at, updated_at FROM table_a WHERE table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id);
```

ActiveRecord analogue for this query:

```
TableB.update_all('(created_at, updated_at) = (SELECT created_at, updated_at FROM table_a WHERE table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id)')
```